# How to change value in one class if value changes in another

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Let's say I have a parameter in my ViewModel:

```
public string ChosenQualityParameter
{
     get => DefectModel.SelectedQualDefectParameters?.Name ?? "Не выбран параметр";
}
```

and I have a class `DefectModel` with parameter `SelectedQualDefectParameters.Name` in it. I want to change the UI binded to `ChosenQualityParameter`, when the`Name` parameter changes too.
But I don't know how to do this properly. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This will give you the tools needed to raise property change events (will have to implement this for the `SelectedQualDefectParameters` property on the `DefectModel`, the `Name` property on the `SelectedQualDefectParameters` and the `ChosenQualityParameter` on your ViewModel) then you ViewModel needs to subscribe to changes to changes (if `SelectQualDefectParameters` changes: unhook your PropertyChanged events from the previous one and rehook it to the new one. If `Name` changes: raise a PropertyChanged event for the `ChosenQualityParameter` on your ViewModel)

Comment: Hi @Knoop, thank you for your answer! I did like you said (added `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for my classes). I didn't understand about raising PropertyChanged() for `ChosenQualityParameter`, how to do that. Are there any examples? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Knoop Is it OK if I use Messaging Center for that? What do you think?

Comment: That depends a bit on how exactly you're using it. Can't check at the moment but in your ViewModel you should be able to call `PropertyChanged(nameof(ChosenQualityParameter))` or something along those lines to raise the property changed event when it's changed. Whether MessagingCenter fits in there depends on the setup of the rest of your application but might be usefull to communicate changes from whatever component manages your `DefectModel` and it's content to your ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Knoop and @BartHofland, I've solved my issue by using `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my `DefectModel` and `SelectedQualDefectParameters` classes.
For setting `ChosenQualityParameter` I used `MessagingCenter` to send new value.

Comment: Very nice. @Knoop: if you supply your solution in an answer, that answer can be marked by Денис Чорный as the correct answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might define your ViewModel class like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private DefectModel _defectModel;

    public ViewModel(DefectModel defectModel)
    {
        _defectModel = defectModel;
    }

    public string ChosenQualityParameter
    {
        get => _defectModel.SelectedQualDefectParameters?.Name ?? "Не выбран параметр";
    }
}
```

I personally do not like such dependencies in viewmodels, but it might get the job done here. It seems to work in a console application anyway:

```
using System;

public class Parameters
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DefectModel
{
    public Parameters SelectedQualDefectParameters { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private DefectModel _defectModel;

    public ViewModel(DefectModel defectModel)
    {
        _defectModel = defectModel;
    }

    public string ChosenQualityParameter
    {
        get => _defectModel.SelectedQualDefectParameters?.Name ?? "Не выбран параметр";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var defectModel = new DefectModel
        {
            SelectedQualDefectParameters = new Parameters
            {
                Name = "test"
            }
        };

        var viewModel = new ViewModel(defectModel);

        Console.WriteLine(viewModel.ChosenQualityParameter);

        defectModel.SelectedQualDefectParameters.Name = "changed";

        Console.WriteLine(viewModel.ChosenQualityParameter);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't think this will help, no property changed event for the `ChosenQualityParameter` parameter will be raised when the name is changed.

Comment: That's right. I misread his question. The UI needs to be updated... But does your construction with INotifyPropertyChanged implementations does that too? As far as I can see, it only updates the ViewModel and does not trigger a UI refresh. But I might be mistaken... In the end, your solution might just have the same functional effect as mine. But without the viewmodel having a dependency on the defectmodel. Instead, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged twice. And in one such implementation, the defectmodel needs to know about the viewmodel it needs to update. Just another dependency?

Comment: @Knoop But perhaps it might be possible to trigger a UI refresh in the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation. In that case, your solution might be better indeed.

Comment: If the UI uses a binding to capture the `ChosenQualityParameter` it should react to the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just re-read your comment and noticed that you would also implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the viewmodel. That should work indeed. I agree that your solution is correct and certainly better than mine.